# Why is my IEnumerable UserControl disposed after I enumerate over it with foreach?

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, ienumerable

I have a usercontrol with an internal list which I have exposed publically by implementing IEnumerable. When I use foreach to enumerate over it, the usercontrol gets disposed. Why is this happening?

Example to reproduce:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class VanishingControl : UserControl, IEnumerable, IEnumerator
{
    string[] strings = { "uno", "due", "tres" };
    int position = -1;

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Current
    {
        get { return strings[position]; }
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        position++;
        return position < strings.Length;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        position = 0;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("bye!");
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}

public class Vanish : Form
{
    private VanishingControl vc = new VanishingControl();

    public Vanish()
    {
        vc.BackColor = Color.Black;
        vc.Click += vc_Click;
        Controls.Add(vc);
    }

    void vc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string s in vc)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new Vanish());
    }
}
```

Run it in the debugger and click the black square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the interfaces implemented by `IEnumerator` is `IDisposable`.  The `foreach` loop will call `Dispose` on the source of the loop once it's done processing the items.

A much better solution would be to factor your `UserControl` into 2 parts

1. The `UserControl` minus the enumerable interfaces
2. A property / method which exposes the collection it contains

For example

```
public class VanishingControl : UserControl
{
  string[] strings = { "uno", "due", "tres" };

  public IEnumerable<string> GetItems() {
    foreach (var current in strings) {
      yield return current;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) (and yes, I just remembered the "yield" thing, and I've done basically what you said except that I put it in the get accessor of a property).

Comment: It's possible (although not necessarily advisable) to leave the IEnumerable on the class without the dispose problem.  It's the IEnumerator that gets disposed, not the IEnumerable.  If you implement GetEnumerator to return "strings.GetEnumerator()", it will create a proper enumerator each time without having to generate an IEnumerable first.

Answer (score 4):

Because your control is its own enumerator :-)

The enumerator is disposed after `foreach` automatically.

I would suggest making the enumerator into a separate class. Or, alternatively, just use a standard collection as a member, and not make the control to be `IEnumerable` itself.

Comment: Yes, in truth I don't see any advantage to implementing IEnumerable in my particular case, so I agree with your suggestion - but I wanted to try this as I had never implemented IEnumerable before, and there are times when it would make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is the cause:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return this;
}
```

One of the `IEnumerator` interface is `IDisposable`, the foreach loop at the end of work invoke the `Dispose` method.

You should provide new IEnumerator each time the GetEnumerator method is called and avoid to use both interfaces in one implementation. This is done by LINQ by but this is specific situtation.

Instead of `IEnumerator` in the class `VanishingControl` you should have a subclass that implement the `IEnumerator` and in GetEnumeratiorn the new instace of that class is returned.

Comment: I did notice that MSDN said it would be best to use a subclass - now I understand why!